# Cordova plugins in Ionic 1 app using Typescript

Tags: angularjs, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm new to Typescript. I just started an Ionic 1.2.4 (Angular) project using Typescript. When transpiling, I receive the error message `Property 'Keyboard' does not exist on type 'CordovaPlugins'` due to the following function passed to `angular.module.run()` in a file `run.ts`

```
///<reference path="../../typings/tsd.d.ts"/>

export function onRun($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  })
}
```

The cordova plugin is in fact installed and it's type definition file definitely exists. Here is the file `tsd.d.ts`.

```
/// <reference path="angularjs/angular.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="cordova/cordova.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="cordova/plugins/BatteryStatus.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="cordova/plugins/Camera.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="cordova/plugins/Contacts.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="cordova/plugins/Device.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="cordova/plugins/DeviceMotion.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="cordova/plugins/DeviceOrientation.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="cordova/plugins/Dialogs.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="cordova/plugins/FileSystem.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="cordova/plugins/FileTransfer.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="cordova/plugins/Globalization.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="cordova/plugins/InAppBrowser.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="cordova/plugins/Keyboard.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="cordova/plugins/Media.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="cordova/plugins/MediaCapture.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="cordova/plugins/NetworkInformation.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="cordova/plugins/Push.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="cordova/plugins/Splashscreen.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="cordova/plugins/StatusBar.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="cordova/plugins/Vibration.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="cordova/plugins/WebSQL.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="ionic/ionic.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="jquery/jquery.d.ts" />
```

I have also tried placing the type definition for Keyboard directly in `run.ts`. `///<reference path="../../typings/cordova/plugins/Keyboard.d.ts"/>`

I'm not expecting the plugin to actually register because 'cordova.js' is not available until the app is built/packaged. I would however like to know how to get Typescript to recognize that `Keyboard` does in fact exist on `cordova.plugins` via type defs. Otherwise, how can I avoid this error during transpilation?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When installing typescript definitions, I did not install `cordova-ionic`. The "standard" cordova Keyboard plugin is distinct from the cordova-ionic Keyboard plugin.

`tsd install cordova-ionic --save` fixed the issue.

Whoops.

Comment: Equivalent command for [typings](https://github.com/typings/typings): `typings install dt~cordova-ionic --global --save`